# Integração com CIELO

Tags: php, api, libcurl

Estou com uma dúvida em como tratar o `--data-binary`, o `header` eu sei que consigo tratar desse forma:

```
$data = [
    'USER'      => $this->username,
    'PWD'       => $this->password,
    'SIGNATURE' => $this->signature,
    'METHOD'    => 'SetExpressCheckout',
    'VERSION'   => 86,
];
```

Agora o `--data-binary` abaixo, eu não sei como atribuir.

```
curl
--data-binary
{  
   "MerchantOrderId":"2014113245231706",
   "Customer":{  
      "Name":"Comprador rec programada"
   },
   "Payment":{  
     "Type":"CreditCard",
     "Amount":1500,
     "Installments":1,
     "SoftDescriptor":"123456789ABCD",
     "RecurrentPayment":{
       "AuthorizeNow":"false",
       "EndDate":"2019-12-01",
       "Interval":"SemiAnnual",
       "StartDate":"2015-06-01"
     },
     "CreditCard":{  
         "CardNumber":"1234123412341231",
         "Holder":"Teste Holder",
         "ExpirationDate":"03/2019",
         "SecurityCode":"262",
         "SaveCard":"false",
         "Brand":"Visa"
     }
   }
}
```

Alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda?

Comment: Consegue ser mais claro na sua pergunta? O que você precisa fazer? Como tentou fazer? Quais erros deram? Adicione isso a pergunta para deixá-la mais fácil de compreendermos.

Comment: Faça um `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` com os dados do `json` tipo, `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json)`. Talvez seja suficiente, mas não estou certo disso.

Comment: a minha dúvida é exatamente como colocar o data-binary dentro do JSON: Eu não sei como tratar as divisões Custumer,payment e Credit Card {  
   "MerchantOrderId":"2014113245231706",
   "Customer":{  
      "Name":"Comprador rec programada"
   },

Comment: Não está clara sua duvida, o `--data-binary` só indica que o que vem seguir é a informação a ser enviada, ele não tem que ser colocado dentro do JSON, isso não tem sentido algum. Por exemplo `curl -d "parametro=valor&outro=coisa"` o `-d` indica que vai ser um `x-www-form-urlencoded` com os valores ("parametro=valor&outro=coisa"), se for `-f` deve fazer um `multipart/form-data`... O `--data-binary` indica, até onde saiba, que deve ser enviado "como está", sem nenhum tratamento pelo CURL. Já a criação do o JSON é outra coisa, que deve estar documentada na API.

Comment: Minha dúvida eh essa, como documentar o JSON na API ? Consegue me ajudar, por favor?